# ReSharper - format expression-bodied members

Tags: c#, formatting, resharper

Is there a setting in ReSharper that allows me to keep the formatting of expression-bodied members?

Currently, I have an expression-bodied member that looks something like this:

```
public bool IsFoo(int foo) => Bar.IsFoo(foo);
```

After running ReSharper formatting it is transformed into this:

```
public bool IsFoo(int foo)
{ 
    return Bar.IsFoo(foo);
}
```

I've tried toggling a few settings but can't seem to find the setting that would control this.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Bodies_of_Function_Members.html#56c2a3c4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Code Style | Code Body | Methods and operators | Select "Expression body" in the drop-down list.